# Нужны ли поставленные запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обстоятельственный-оборот

«В связи с этим, в ближайшее время, будет собрана и предоставлена статистика по несоответствующему сырью для компенсации финансовых потерь».

Нужны ли поставленные запятые и почему?

Answer (score 2):

*В связи с этим в ближайшее время будет собрана и предоставлена статистика по несоответствующему сырью для компенсации финансовых потерь.*

Запятые не нужны.

Оборот ***в связи с этим*** не отделяется запятой (см. [ответы Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%2C)).
Обстоятельственный оборот ***в ближайшее время*** в данном случае тоже не требует обособления. Он ничего не уточняет, стоит в начале предложения, не разбивает подлежащее и сказуемое, не имеет каких-либо добавочных оттенков значения (хотя, конечно, без контекста об этом судить сложно).
Вообще, обособление обстоятельств, выраженных существительными с предлогами, факультативно и зависит от многих факторов (см. [справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)).